# App Widget won't show in app drawer, seems related to Invalid dimensions

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am getting the following error in LogCat:

> 03-16 23:33:47.239: E/Rosie.AppsCustomizePag_(19861): Widget  WidgetSummary(TestApp/APP_WIDGET/0 x 
>   0/-1/ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.ExampleAppWidgetProvider}/0/false) has invalid dimensions (0, 0)

Here is my layout for the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/example_widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
</appwidget-provider>
```

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?  I am very new to Android. Any other information needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof.  I had an extra ">" in the xml file.  Messed everything up.

Comment: Haha, I also had it for some reason! I think I would spend days to find it if I didn't see your post, thanks for sharing!